# Taxonomies exists - but not showing up

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

In the functions.php of my child-theme I created some CPT with taxonomies.

```
add_action('init', 'register_ap_jobverzeichnis');
function register_ap_jobverzeichnis() {
  global $jobdata;

  $ap_jobver_rewrite = $jobdata['ap_jobver_rewrite'];
  if(empty($ap_jobver_rewrite)) { 
    $ap_jobver_rewrite = 'jobboerse'; 
  }

  $joblabels = array(
    'name'               => __('Jobverzeichnis','frameworkjob'),
    'singular_name'      => __('Jobverzeichnis','frameworkjob'),
    'add_new'            => __('Neuer Job','frameworkjob'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Neuen Job hinzufügen','frameworkjob'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Job bearbeiten','frameworkjob'),
    'new_item'           => __('Neuer Job','frameworkjob'),
    'view_item'          => __('Job ansehen','frameworkjob'),
    'search_items'       => __('Job suchen','frameworkjob'),
    'not_found'          =>  __('Keine Jobs gefunden','frameworkjob'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Keine Jobs im Papierkorb','frameworkjob'),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Jobverzeichnis'
  );

  $jobargs = array(
    'labels' => $joblabels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'Stellenangebote',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => $ap_jobver_rewrite),
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/jobverzeichnis/job.png',
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_position' => 12,
    'taxonomies' => array('jobfelder'),
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'excerpt',
      'thumbnail',
      'page-attributes'
    )
  );

  $jobtaxlabels = array(
    'name'                       => __('Tätigkeitsfelder', 'frameworkjob'),
    'singular_name'              => __('Tätigkeitsfelder', 'frameworkjob'),
    'search_items'               => __('Tätigkeitsfelder suchen', 'frameworkjob'),
    'popular_items'              => __('Häufige Tätigkeitsfelder', 'frameworkjob'),
    'all_items'                  => __('Alle Tätigkeitsfelder', 'frameworkjob'),
    'parent_item'                => __('Eltern-Tätigkeitsfeld', 'frameworkjob'),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __('Eltern-Tätigkeitsfeld:', 'frameworkjob'),
    'edit_item'                  => __('Tätigkeitsfeld bearbeiten', 'frameworkjob'),
    'update_item'                => __('Tätigkeitsfeld aktualisieren', 'frameworkjob'),
    'add_new_item'               => __('Tätigkeitsfeld hinzufügen', 'frameworkjob'),
    'new_item_name'              => __('Neue Tätigkeitsfeld', 'frameworkjob'),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Tätigkeitsfelder mit Kommas trennen', 'frameworkjob'),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Tätigkeitsfeld hinzu/ entfernen', 'frameworkjob'),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used Project types', 'frameworkjob'),
    'menu_name'                  => __('Tätigkeitsfelder', 'frameworkjob')
  );


  register_post_type('jobboerse',$jobargs);

  register_taxonomy('jobfelder', array('jobboerse'),
    array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'labels' => $jobtaxlabels,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'jobfelder',
        'hierarchical' => true
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Then in a page with own template I want to output the taxonomies with

```
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('jobfelder');
if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0) {
  foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax) {
    $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => 1, 'pad_counts' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 1, 'taxonomy' => $tax, 'title_li' => '');
    wp_list_categories($args);
  }
}
```

But I get no output.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post your `register_post_type()` and `register_taxonomy()` functions completely in the order they appear.

Comment: Did it. Hope now its more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies with the use of [`get_object_taxonomies( $object, $output )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies). If you have a look at the codex, the `$object` parameter should be

> Name of the post type, or a post object (row from posts)

As your code currently stands, you are using the taxonomy name, not post type. If you print `$customPostTaxonomies` with

```
print_r( $customPostTaxonomies);
```

you get `Array()`, that is why you get no output.

When you change `get_object_taxonomies('jobfelder');` to `get_object_taxonomies('jobboerse');`, your code works and output the names of the taxonomies which is related to your custom post type 'jobboerse'

**EDIT**

Thanks to @cfx

> Better be safe than sorry when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` **right after the function (emphasis added)** to interconnect them.

Comment: Also don't forget to use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` immediately after your `register_taxonomy()` function.

Comment: That was the point @Pieter Goosen. Seems I was blind of my own code.

Comment: @cfx: also thank you. Don't have 'register_taxonomy_for_object_type()' in my code. Need that?

Comment: From [the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) "Better be safe than sorry when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` *right after the function* (emphasis added) to interconnect them."

Comment: @BRLNbrainBUG please accept my answer then by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer just below the up/down arrows. Thanks

Comment: @Pieter Goosen: never noticed that checkmark. Thank you!